# How to fix wget download file name when the url is redirected

Tags: http, shell, url, download, wget

`Wget` can't detect filename when 301/302 redirections.  For example, to download the MySQL source code from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=408580

```
wget http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
```

The file will be save as `index.html`

```
wget http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz
```

The file will be save as `mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz`

but the first url is only a redirection for second URL as it is shown in:

```
curl -I http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2012 06:11:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: mirror=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.mysql.com%2F; expires=Sat, 08-Jul-2017 06:11:50 GMT; path=/
Location: http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

How can `wget` save http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/ as ".tar.gz" automatically (without using `-O` argument)?

Comment: See also [this Unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74334/87770). My solution (posted and explained in comments there) was to use `--trust-server-names`

Comment: Ah, and there's another SO question on this as well: see [How to rename the downloaded file with wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306382/how-to-rename-the-downloaded-file-with-wget)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
wget --content-disposition http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.25a-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
```

When this is set to on, the experimental (not fully-functional) support for "*Content-Disposition*" header is enabled. This can result in extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD" request and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by default.

This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use "*Content-Disposition*" header to describe what the name of a downloaded file should be.