# How to rename the downloaded file with wget?

Tags: wget, file-rename

To download the SOFA Statistics from the server I use the wget command:

```
wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/sofastatistics/files/latest/download?source=dlp
```

The filename of downloaded file in this case is `download?source=files`. If I add the `--output-document` option to the command, to rename the output file to `sofastatistics-latest.deb`, the format of downloaded file is not recognized by dpkg package.

```
dpkg-deb: error: `sofastatistics-latest.deb' is not a debian format archive
```

How to rename correctly the downloaded file with wget?

**UPDATE - *Jan 08 '15***

With the provided link the downloaded file always will be a *.tar.gz one. To get it with the real name just add the `--content-disposition` option as this (thanks to @6EQUJ5!):

```
wget --content-disposition http://sourceforge.net/projects/sofastatistics/files/latest/download?source=dlp
```

But I needed a *.deb file, so here was right the @creaktive, I had to search for a *.deb file link.

Thanks to all for the answers!

Comment: If dpkg says that, it _really_ is not a Debian archive... What does `file` say?

Comment: The URL you mentioned is a HTML page.

Comment: I think you accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: @user83039 It isn't wrong, it is partial, but you are right, I must not accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: I've found `--trust-server-names` is more appropriate for my uses.  See also this [duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389933/how-to-fix-wget-download-file-name-when-the-url-is-redirected) and the [same question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/how-to-download-files-with-wget-where-the-page-makes-you-wait-for-download).

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[wget command to download a file and save as a different filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Probably, you want to say that the question you mentioned is a possible duplicate of my question? See the publication date.

Answer (score 135):

A redirect of standard output into arbitrary file name always works. You are doing it correctly as **man wget** says, using -O

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/README -O foo
--2013-01-13 18:59:44--  http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/README
Resolving www.kernel.org... 149.20.4.69, 149.20.20.133
Connecting to www.kernel.org|149.20.4.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12056 (12K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `foo'

100%[======================================================================================================================================>] 12,056      --.-K/s   in 0.003s  

2013-01-13 18:59:45 (4.39 MB/s) - `foo' saved [12056/12056]
```

Indeed, you must be getting an HTML in your file (usually can be checked with **man file**).

**[EDIT]**

In your case client is receiving *302 Found* (you can check it with **curl -v URL**).

The following curl does the trick by respecting the 3xx:

```
$ curl -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/sofastatistics/files/latest/download?source=files -o foo.deb
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   463    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
100 2035k  100 2035k    0     0   390k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 1541k
$ file foo.deb 
foo.deb: gzip compressed data, was "sofastats-1.3.1.tar", last modified: Thu Jan 10 00:30:44 2013, max compression
```

There should be similar option for **wget** to tolerate HTTP redirects.

Answer (score 24):

If you were to do the same download from a web browser, and you notice the browser actually naming the file correctly,  you can use the `--content-disposition` option to give wget the same behaviour:

```
wget --content-disposition http://sourceforge.net/projects/sofastatistics/files/latest/download?source=dlp
```

My Debian man page reports this as an 'experimental' feature but I cant recall it not working for me:

```
       --content-disposition
           If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can currently result in extra round-trips to the server
           for a "HEAD" request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by default.

           This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use "Content-Disposition" headers to describe what the name of a downloaded file should be.
```

Answer (score 1):

That link points to a redirector, not the final destination! So you're downloading HTML and renaming it to `.deb`. The cluttered page has this around the top:

> Your download will start in 0 seconds...
>   Problems with the download? Please use this [direct link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sofastatistics/sofastatistics/1.3.1/sofastats-1.3.1_for_mac.zip?r=&ts=1358099896&use_mirror=ufpr), or try another [mirror](http://sourceforge.net/settings/mirror_choices?projectname=sofastatistics&filename=sofastatistics/1.3.1/sofastats-1.3.1_for_mac.zip).

Now, *this* is a valid link (note the `download` prefix):
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sofastatistics/sofastatistics/1.3.1/sofastats-1.3.1-1_all.deb?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fsofastatistics%2Ffiles%2Fsofastatistics%2F1.3.1%2F&ts=1358119361&use_mirror=ufpr

Pass this URL to `wget`.
Also, note that SourceForge tries to outsmart you, guesting the operational system via the User-Agent string. The best guess for "wget" seems to be the .tar.gz package. So, you should be more specific, requesting the deb file!

Comment: There is a .tar.gz version for this software: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sofastatistics/files/sofastatistics/1.3.1/ Make sure you select the .deb link!

Answer (score 1):

This worked out for me

- on macOS I installed `wget` via Homebrew so with this `brew install wget`
- then I execute this `wget -O ~/Downloads/file.txt https://www.gnu.org`
- or this is the same `wget --output-document ~/Downloads/fil.txt https://www.gnu.org`