# How to change filename of a file downloaded with wget?

Tags: download, wget

I am downloading a file from `www.examplesite.com/textfile.txt`

When running the following command

```
wget www.examplesite.com/textfile.txt
```

the file is saved as `textfile`. How can I save it as `newfile.txt`?

Comment: It's `wget -O newfile.txt`.

Comment: but wget -o will simply give you the progress of downloading as a logfile. I tried wget -o.

Comment: `wget -o` will output log information to a file.  `wget -O` will output the downloaded content.  `man wget` will tell you all of this and more.

Comment: What @AndyRoss said: mind the capitalisation; it's commonly MEANINGFUL in unix/linux land.

Comment: Ohhh, I missed out on the Caps. I was trying the lower case o until @AndyRoss pointed out. It worked.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The OUTPUT of the command  will be saved to -o file, but the file itself will be downloaded with the same name and not "saved as".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Is there a way to get the filename that `wget` will use for the output file? I'd like to use `wget`'s default name and then process the file afterwards, but to do the post processing I need the name that `wget` used for the file.

Answer (score 1235, accepted):

Use the `-O file` option.

E.g.

```
wget google.com
...
16:07:52 (538.47 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [10728]
```

vs.

```
wget -O foo.html google.com
...
16:08:00 (1.57 MB/s) - `foo.html' saved [10728]
```

Comment: Man pages reveal: "Use of -O is not intended to mean simply 'use the name file instead of the one in the URL;' rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: ``wget -O file http://foo`` is intended to work like ``wget -O - http://foo > file``; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there."

Comment: How would one append to foo.html instead of overwriting it?

Comment: @CraigJacobs you can output `wget` in console and append it to file. For example `wget -O - -o /dev/null  http://google.com >> foo.html`. [Reference](http://serverfault.com/questions/25779/how-do-i-pipe-a-downloaded-file-to-standard-output-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @javadba, on Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) only your syntax works, as it seems true for Centos6 as seen in other answer (the answer is edited pending acceptance)

Comment: This approach would render --timestamping ineffective

Comment: This command won't create the file if the directory doesn't exist before

Comment: Not to be confused with `-o`!

Comment: Is it possible to merely choose the file stem, and let `wget` apply the extension of the file you're downloading? Ex `wget -P /my/dir --stem foo https://example.com/img.jpg` → `/my/dir/foo.jpg`

Answer (score 159):

Also notice the order of parameters on the command line. At least on some systems (e.g. CentOS 6):

```
wget -O FILE URL
```

works. But:

```
wget URL -O FILE
```

does not work.

Comment: seems OK on debian bullseye for ARM64

Answer (score 46):

You would use the command Mechanical snail listed. Notice the uppercase O. Full command line to use could be:

```
wget www.examplesite.com/textfile.txt --output-document=newfile.txt
```

or

```
wget www.examplesite.com/textfile.txt -O newfile.txt
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `--output-document=newfile.txt` is what worked for me. All attempts to use -O failed with the error `Resolving webmin_1.630_all.deb (webmin_1.630_all.deb)... failed: Name or service not known.`

Answer (score 30):

Either `curl` or `wget` can be used in this case. All 3 of these commands do the same thing, downloading the file at http://path/to/file.txt and saving it locally into "my_file.txt".

*Note that in all commands below, I also recommend using the `-L` or `--location` option with `curl` in order to follow HTML 302 redirects to the new location of the file, if it has moved. `wget` requires no additional options to do this, as it does this automatically.*

```bash
# save the file locally as my_file.txt

wget http://path/to/file.txt -O my_file.txt  # my favorite--it has a progress bar
curl -L http://path/to/file.txt -o my_file.txt
curl -L http://path/to/file.txt > my_file.txt
```

Alternatively, to save the file as the same name locally as it is remotely, use either `wget` by itself, or `curl` with `-O` or `--remote-name`:

```bash
# save the file locally as file.txt

wget http://path/to/file.txt
curl -LO http://path/to/file.txt
curl -L --remote-name http://path/to/file.txt
```

*Notice that the `-O` in all of the commands above is the capital letter "O".*

The nice thing about the `wget` command is it shows a nice progress bar.

You can prove the files downloaded by each of the sets of 3 techniques above are exactly identical by comparing their sha512 hashes. Running `sha512sum my_file.txt` after running each of the commands above, and comparing the results, reveals all 3 files to have the exact same sha hashes (sha sums), meaning the files are exactly identical, byte-for-byte.

### References

1. I learned about the `-L` option with `curl` here: [Is there a way to follow redirects with command line cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474746/4561887)

<sub>See also: [How to capture cURL output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411327/4561887)</sub>

Answer (score 26):

```
wget -O yourfilename.zip remote-storage.url/theirfilename.zip
```

will do the trick for you.

Note:

a) its a capital O.

b) **`wget -O filename url`** will only work. Putting **`-O`** last will not.

Answer (score 14):

Using CentOS Linux I found that the easiest syntax would be:

```bash
wget "link" -O file.ext
```

where `"link"` is the web address you want to save and `"file.ext"` is the filename and extension of your choice.

Comment: I dont understand answering an already-answered-question with the same answer 2 years later..