# Wget download file using PHP exec

Tags: php, linux

Is it possible to download a file using Wget? I want download that file into my default browser's download directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wget command to download a file and save as a different filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename)

Comment: i want to download it into default download directory using php.And it will work as a normal file download

Comment: Browser is client-side. PHP is server-side. There is something wrong with your request...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it wouldn't achieve the effect you desire.

Running `wget` would cause the file to be downloaded to the server (which is something you'd be better off using the `cURL` library for instead of shelling out to an external binary).

If you want the browser to download it, then you need to output the file from PHP, not save it to a file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
shell_exec('wget -P path_to_default_download_directory google.com');
```