# Automatically changing name of downloaded files using Python

Tags: python, replace

This script loops through a list of url's which download csv files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

file = open('links20151111.txt','r')
for url in file:
        print ('[+] downloadin ' + url.strip())
        subprocess.call(['wget', '--content-disposition', url.strip()])
```

The url's do not contain the file names.

The thing that needs to be done is to replace all "-" with "_" in the file names.
A file name could be like this, "traffic_injuries_2001-2014.csv".

Comment: Your example doesn't replace "all" `-`s with `_`s, just the first two. Can you define that requirement more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you could loop through the files in your download directory each time you download a new file and look for the file with a dash in it, then make the character replacement on that file. This should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, os

def rename_file():
    for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()): 
        if '-' in f and f.endswith('.csv'): 
            os.rename(f,f.replace('-','_'))

file = open('links20151111.txt','r')
for url in file:
        print ('[+] downloadin ' + url.strip())
        subprocess.call(['wget', '--content-disposition', url.strip()])
        rename_file()
```

Depending on how the file names are structured you may need to tighten the criteria for your file search. You could compile a regular expression to match the text format more strictly.

Comment: I solved it using this code:
`#!/usr/bin/python


import os

path  = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
 os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace('-', '_')))`

Thank's for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-O` option:

```
wget google.com -O foo.html
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename).

Otherwise I would suggest using [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) module: [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)