# How to specify file names to the multiple files we are downloading using wget -I command in linux?

Tags: linux, wget

We can download multiple links using `wget -i file_name` where `file_name` is the file that contains all URLs we have to download.

I have 3 URLs in a file for example:

```
google.com
facebook.com
twitter.com
```

I request these URLs using `wget -i file_name`. But, how can we specify files names to store the result?

For example,we have to store result from google.com, facebook.com, twitter.com as response1, response2, response3 respectively. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man curl` and look at `-o` option? And sorry, but IMHO, this doesn't qualify as a programming Q. In the future, please post at http://superuser.com . Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I found similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename)
Use the `-O file` option.

E.g.

```
wget google.com
...
16:07:52 (538.47 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [10728]
```

vs.

```
wget -O foo.html google.com
...
16:08:00 (1.57 MB/s) - `foo.html' saved [10728]
```

---

Referring above I come up with a solution to write a simple shell script.

> It's simply like executing `wget -O <URL> <filename>` multiple times.

1. Create a file `download_file.sh` with contents like this

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   wget https://www.google.com -O google_file
   wget https://www.facebook.com -O fb_file
   wget https://www.twitter.com -O twitter_file
   ```
2. Make the file executable

   ```
   chmod +x download_file.sh
   ```
3. Run the file

   ```
   ./download_file.sh
   ```

All URL will be downloaded with filename defined in the `download_file.sh`. Also, you can tweak the shell script as your requirement like providing URLs from another file as the argument of this file.