# Setting required to do wget from a linux http server

Tags: linux, wget

I would like to wget a file from an http server like:

`wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=<username> --http-passwd=<passwd> https://<file_path>`

1. What are the initial ssh setup required?
2. What do i update in the know_hosts on the remote system?
3. Is a restart reuired?

Comment: As far as I know wget uses http and does not require any ssh setup. Is the server is public domain? An example may ease to find exact arguments to wget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wget command to download a file and save as a different filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename)

Answer (score 2):

```
1. What are the initial ssh setup required?
```

You do not need ssh setup to be able to use wget. If you are on linux, it should be built-in. You can confirm that by typing :

```
$ type wget
```

If you get a response like

```
wget is /usr/local/bin/wget
```

you are good to go. No setup needed.

```
2. What do i update in the know_hosts on the remote system?
```

Nothing again, that file is specific to ssh. Leave it alone.

```
3. Is a restart reuired?
```

No, not even if you were to install wget.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do two things:

1. Install Apache on your Ubuntu installations. The command to use is
   `sudo apt-get install apache2`.
2. Copy or move your `file.conf` to the folder at `/var/www`. You might
   need to use `sudo` for this again: for example, `sudo cp
   /path/to/your/file.conf /var/www/file.conf`.

wget will probably not work with wildcards. A better solution will be to do something like this as a shell script, once all your configuration files are accessible:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}

do

wget "127.0.$i.1"

done
```

> another solution

`note` wget will only be able to download anything if there is an HTTP server running at the other end.

s you may be able to run commands via ssh in bulk, this might help:

```
# on the client machine:
cd /home/username/Pictures/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This starts a web-server on the machine it's run on. You can then access the file from anywhere using

```
wget http://172.29.34.15:8000/x.jpeg
```

Comment: Though i provide correct passwd and username i get the error "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="Intranet ID and Password"
Reusing existing connection to <server_name:portnumber>
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Username/Password Authentication Failed."