# Removing file from folder in linux

Tags: linux, hive

**Linux os**

Hello

i have downloaded the file using wget. the file downloaded with some messy name like

```
index.html?format=csv&timezone=Asia%2FKolkata&use_labels_for_header=true.
```

now i am trying to remove this file using rm, but its not getting removed.

**Linux os**

```
sudo rm -f Unconfirmed\sudo rm -f Unconfirmed\index.html?format=csv&timezone=Asia%2FKolkata&use_labels_for_header=true
```

how can i removed it from folder.

Comment: 1) Check file permissions. 2) Try enclosing filename in double quotes. Other than that, looks like your file contains special characters that aren't interpreted correctly by rm command. You can provide a cleaner output filename with [wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678487/wget-command-to-download-a-file-and-save-as-a-different-filename). The rm command is explained here [how to remove all files from a directory on linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RebdJu5fn0M) and you can also use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as below. Make sure you have permission for that file/folder to edit(delete or update). You have used sudo that is correct.

- To remove the folder with all its contents(including all interior
  folders):

  ```
    rm -rf /path/to/directory
  ```
- To remove all the contents of the    folder(including all interior folders) but not the folder itself:

  ```
    rm -rf /path/to/directory/* or

    rm -rf /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
  ```

  if you want to make sure that hidden    files/directories are also removed.
- To remove all the "files" from inside a folder(not removing interior    folders):

  ```
    rm -f /path/to/directory/{*,.*} 
   Where:
    rm - stands for "remove"   
    -f - stands for "force" which is helpful when you don't want to be asked/prompted 
    if you want to remove an archive, for example.   
    -r - stands for "recursive" which means that you want to go 
    recursively down every folder and remove everything.
  ```

Answer (score 1):

rm -rf "yourfilename" put double quotes over your file name.
Also check if you have permission to delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

make notifies you of the deletion by printing an ***rm -f*** command that specifies the file it is deleting.

Eg: [image]

Here `MergeSort` is the file that I need to remove.