# How can you delete specific files in /temp in site server?

Tags: linux, server, terminal, putty

My site is experiencing Internal server Errors, website shutdowns and the main cause is a full `/temp` directory. The support gave us a list of large temp files that come with a size exceeding 1 GB. Is there any way to delete specific files in `/temp`?

```
ls -lah /tmp
```

I've used this code to go to my `/temp` file. How can I delete specific files in it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing file from folder in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889471/removing-file-from-folder-in-linux)

Comment: Are you talking about a `/temp` or a `/tmp` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change directory to tmp - `cd /tmp`

And delete specific files - `rm -f specific.file.name`

Comment: this is what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` for that:

```
find /temp -size +1G -delete
```

This means the following:

```
/temp     : location of the search (subfolders are searched too)
-size +1G : the size should be larger than 1Gb
-delete   : once such a file is found, delete it.
```